# jquery plugin history not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am using the the jquery history plugin from http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html.

I am not able to get the plugin to work on IE8. In Firefox it works as expected. IE8 works on the sample at the site of the plugin-creator.

My site contains 3 links. I click entry 1 through 3 first. When entry 3 is shown I hit the back button and get to the url http://localhost:5000/de/Playground/HistoryTest#link2. The correct entry is displayed.

The forward button of the browser is not shown, but it should be shown.

Then I hit the back button again, but I dont get to entry 1: instead I get to entry 3.

Anybody knows if I am doing something wrong?

Here is the script. I use

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  > 

  function callbackHistory(hash) {
    if (hash != '') {


      if ($.browser.msie) {
        // jquery's $.load() function does't work when hash include special characters like aao.
        hash = encodeURIComponent(hash);
      }

      //alert(hash);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/de/Playground/HistoryDetail",
        data: {
          DataKey: hash
        },
        success: function(htmlSource) {
          $("#ajaxContainer").html(htmlSource);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.history.init(callbackHistory);


    $("a").click(function() {

      $.history.load(this.href.replace(/^.*#/, ''));
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HMTL**

```
<a href="#link1" rel="history"   >link1 </a>
<a href="#link2" rel="history"  >link2 </a>
<a href="#link3" rel="history"  >link3 </a>

<div id="ajaxContainer" >
</div>
```

The Server Part only renders an HTML snippet that inlcudes the hash.

```
<h3>
<%= hash >
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I used an old version of the plugin.

The header of the plugin I used sais:

2006 Taku Sano

but the recent file has

2006-2009 Taku Sano

I used the sample from the "Jquery Cookbook". That sample used the old plugin. The sample on the page of the plugin author uses the recent version and works in IE.